Set global DNS in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm having a hard time to set a DNS server in Ubuntu 24.04.
I want to run a script which sets a DNS server on any computer. I tried to use Netplan with the following:
ethernets:
  if0:
    match:
      name: e*
      name: w*
    nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.111.12]

...but it doesn't work.
Even when I try the following:
ethernets:
  eth0:
    nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.111.12]

...it's not working.
I've got it working somehow until next change, but I have no idea how. Everything I try doesn't work. I already reinstalled Ubuntu and working on a plain system.
It seems to me with Netplan you have to configure the whole interface (with DHCP and stuff), but this is impossible since it should set the DNS on any network.
Do you guys have any ides how I can get this done?

You say you want to run a script...what script? Can you provide the contents of the script? Also, please provide the output of ip a.  Finally, are you using a Desktop or Server installation? Add additional information by editing/updating your original question. Do not add in comments.
